# Getting an error on a package that I installed in my project Highway.js Tweenmax

Tags: javascript, gsap

Im getting this error:

```
slide_up.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
    at _inherits (slide_up.js:2)
    at slide_up.js:6
    at Object.parcelRequire.js/slide_up.js.@dogstudio/highway (slide_up.js:18)
    at newRequire (main.fb6bbcaf.js:47)
    at localRequire (main.fb6bbcaf.js:53)
    at Object.parcelRequire.js/main.js.@dogstudio/highway (main.js:2)
    at newRequire (main.fb6bbcaf.js:47)
    at main.fb6bbcaf.js:81
    at main.fb6bbcaf.js:120
```

on an import in slide_up.js.. I'm using an animation library and a package called highway.js. I tried to install @babel/core.. I'm really not too sure what the error means, any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import Highway from '@dogstudio/highway';
import { TimelineLite } from 'gsap';



class SlideUp extends Highway.transition {
  //responsible for page coming in
  in({ from, to, done }) {
    const timeline = new TimelineLite();

    timeline.fromTo(to, 0.5, {top: '100%'}, {top: '0%', onComplete: function(){
      done();
    }})
  }
  //responsible for page going out
  out({ from, done }) {
    done();
  }
}


export default SlideUp;
```